# Is there a way in pygame to make a programme pause when it's minimized?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I was playing Terraria the other day and in a new update they make the game pause when it's minimized. Obviously it's written in a different programme to python, but I was wondering if it was possible to replicate the effects.

Comment: Did you try ? Show your code.

Comment: answer for your question: yes, it possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pygame.display.get_active()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.iconify) to check if window is minimized.

In example you can press `SPACE` to minimize window.

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

count = 0

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                pygame.display.iconify()

    if pygame.display.get_active():
        print count
        count +=1
    else:
        print "minimized"

pygame.quit()
```

Or you can use `pygame.ACTIVEEVENT` to get information about more events - like minimize, mouse out of the window, etc.

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

count = 0

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                pygame.display.iconify()
        elif event.type == pygame.ACTIVEEVENT:
            print 'state:', event.state, '| gain:', event.gain, 
            if event.state == 1:
                if event.gain == 0:
                    print "| mouse out",
                elif event.gain == 1:
                    print "| mouse in",
            elif event.state == 2:
                if event.gain == 0:
                    print "| titlebar pressed",
                elif event.gain == 1:
                    print "| titlebar unpressed",
            elif event.state == 6:
                if event.gain == 0:
                    print "| window minimized",
            elif event.state == 4:
                if event.gain == 1:
                    print "| window normal",
            print

pygame.quit()
```

Both method work correctly only if `pygame.event.get()` was executed.

Comment: Thanks guys. Massive help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pygame.APPACTIVE event. From the documentation for the pygame.display.iconify:

`Then the display mode is set, several events are placed on the pygame event queue. pygame.QUIT is sent when the user has requested the program to shutdown. The window will receive pygame.ACTIVEEVENT events as the display gains and loses input focus [This is when the window is minimized]. If the display is set with the pygame.RESIZABLE flag, pygame.VIDEORESIZE events will be sent when the user adjusts the window dimensions. Hardware displays that draw direct to the screen will get pygame.VIDEOEXPOSE events when portions of the window must be redrawn.`

Look at the second example in furas' answer below, but don't use the polling approach of the first example for something like this, you don't want to spend time every frame trying to check if the window has been minimized.

Comment: What documentation do you use because I didn't find this text in [pygame.display.iconify](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.iconify) on [pygame.org](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html).

Comment: But there is a `ACTIVEEVENT` not `APPACTIVE` - and you have `APPACTIVE` in your text.

Comment: And why you use my example in your answer ? Make own.

Comment: I suspect that the [docs](http://un1pr0g.free.fr/wikini/wakka.php?wiki=PygameD&show_comments=1) I'm looking at translated that somehow (even though it's in english on the page), I'll replace it with the text from PyGame.org which uses ACTIVEEVENT

Comment: @furas I didn't realize I was doing anything wrong by consolidating answers on the page. In my opinion your first answer was wrong, and the edit added the correct answer, but the answer I view as wrong (or at least bad practice) is still there. I also clearly mentioned it was from this page.

Comment: You could add only text `see example below` or something like this. I think you could use my example to create better solution. First example shows how to use `pygame.display.get_active()` to check if window is minimized. I show two possible solution. OP will decide which one OP prefer.

Comment: Sure both solutions work in theory, but polling shouldn't be forced here. This is like someone asking how they know if they're hungry. using get_active is like telling them to eat something and see if they throw up every 5 minutes, using the event is like telling them to do what ever they want and just wait until their stomach is rumbling. It's important to show the best practice, not all remotely possible ones, you don't want to give a choice between a clearly inferior approach and a better one to someone who doesn't know the difference (or at the very least without explaining that)

Comment: Also answers are added, removed and rearranged (already my reference to below was wrong), so I don't see the harm in re-posting an example. I didn't take credit for it if that's what you're so worried about.